# iOS Cross Dissolve WITHOUT a darker middle

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

We are trying to do a dissolve between two almost exact images (almost animation frames) but so far we cannot remove the darkening that happens midway through the dissolve. The client is very firm about not having this darker dissolve, anything thought?

```
 UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageViewSmileDesign.frame];
newImageView.image = imageViewSmileDesign.image;
[self.view addSubview:newImageView];

imageViewSmileDesign.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", result]];
imageViewSmileDesign.alpha = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    imageViewSmileDesign.alpha = 1;
    newImageView.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [newImageView removeFromSuperview];
} ];
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the cross-disolve animation that's built into [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a):

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Set options to `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve`.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't change the alpha of 'newImageView' to 0. This will cause the new image to fade on top of the old one, and you don't have this half-way state where they are both semi-transparent revealing the background color.

You will have to bring `imageViewSmileDesign` to the front with a call to `bringSubviewToFront:` before the animation.

Answer (score 0):

If both images have the same frame, just remove `newImageView.alpha = 0;`. That'll do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delay the START of the newImageView.alpha fade.